# How to print the minimum level node that is bigger than a given number in Binary Tree using BFS?

Tags: java

I need to print the node value of the minimum level in binary tree that is bigger than a given number (we can call it 'k') using BFS.

Comment: Then you should write code to do that; if you have trouble doing so, come back with what you have tried & what you are stuck on.

Comment: _minimum level_ = minimum depth of the path from the root? Try it out on paper.

Comment: Please give an example for the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printBiggerMinLevel(Node root, int k) {//Using BFS 
        int chosen = 0, level = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(root == null) return;
        if(root.getVal() > k) {
            System.out.println(root.getVal());
            return;
        }
        Queue<Node> q = new Queue<>();
        q.enqueue(root);
        Node cur;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            cur = q.dequeue();
            if(cur.getVal() > k)
                if(cur.getLevel() < level) {
                    chosen = cur.getVal();
                    level = cur.getLevel();
                }
            if(cur.getLeftSon() != null)
                q.enqueue(cur.getLeftSon());
            if(cur.getRightSon() != null)
                q.enqueue(cur.getRightSon());
        }
        System.out.println(chosen);
    }
```